Blender background plane color banding issue
I’m rendering a turntable and getting pretty nasty banding on the background plane. Does anyone know how to fix this? I found an old video on YouTube that suggested changing the color depth to 16-bit and setting the dither to 2, but that didn’t help. Does anyone have any other solutions? I’ve tried rendering as PNG and EXR, but neither worked.


Well, noise could help to "reduce it" a bit. Another thing that you could try is to Render in 32 bit. But you are probably not going to fix it 100%. Also, it could be that your monitor can only display 8 or 10 bits at a time.

remove the character and upload the .blend with the background https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486
